# URL hashing in django web application

Tags: python, django, url, dictionary

If users' url type patterns are settled, for example,

```
1. myurl.com/feeds/recnets/

2. myurl.com/feeds/users/

3. myurl.com/feeds/tags/

4. myurl.com/feeds/~
```

I want to make a dictionary to pass specific function from those patterns.

So I make a dictionary type in **urls.py** and passing its dictionary parameters. (see below)

```
 1 import os.path
 2 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 3 from bookmarks.views import *
 4 from django.contrib import admin
 5 from django.views.generic import TemplateView
 6 from bookmarks.feeds import *
 7 
 8 admin.autodiscover()
 9 
 10 site_media = os.path.join(
 11         os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
 12 )
 13 
 14 feeds = {
 15     'recents' : RecentBookmarks(),
 16     'user' : UserBookmarks()
 17 }
 18 
 19 urlpatterns = patterns('',
 20     # Feeds 
 21     (r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)$',
 22         feeds),
```

As I expected, it did not work because **urls.py** did not differentiate parameters' name.

I also referred django project document to resolve this problem, but I could not found it how to pass hash arguments to function at url side.

Comment: to make clear . u have different functions in view for recent,user,tag.is it right

Comment: @SundarNataraj yes it is. I made it and imported it in my project folder

Comment: Have the below code looks as u intented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elaborate the Above answer.

It is always better to **Keep App specific urls in each app folder's urls.py file**. You can then include urls of each app in your root urls.py file.

e.g

```
Project/
  -- urls.py   # Root urls.py
  -- app1/
     --- urls.py   # App specific urls.py
  -- app2/
     --- urls.py
```

And each **URL should have its own Pattern and related to a view** e.g

```
### app1/urls.py ###    
urlpatterns = (
        url(r'^recents/$', RecentBookmarks.as_view()),
       # Samefor all the urls
    )
```

For more info on **including url patterns** see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

For further learning, you can also look into **how to use url Name-spacing** here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

Answer (score 1):

in project folder: according `Django 1.6`
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from bookmarks import *

urlpatterns = [
    # ... snip ...

    url(r'^feeds/', include('bookmarks.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
]
```

in bookmarks folder create file urls.py

```
from bookmarks import *

from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^recents/$', 'bookmarks.view.RecentBookmarks'),
    url(r'^user/$', 'bookmarks.view.UserBookmarks'),
   #so on for all the urls
]
```

Note: feel free edit the code if there is mistake in importing

Comment: Do you mean dissociate urls into two .py files, first, urls.py in project folder, and bookmarks/urls.py to hash all of user's input?

Comment: yes .. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs check this